# How to fix the laptop hanging when JavaScript yarn test are launched?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, hadoop-yarn, freeze

When running `yarn test` all 20 CPU cores are occupied by Node.js and the laptop hangs in. Most of the apps written in NodeJS/Electron like Skype, MS Teams and Slack are killed by OS.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

RAM: 32 GB

CPU: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i9-12900H × 20

Answer (score 2):

After adding `maxWorkers` parameters it fixed the issue:

```
yarn test --maxWorkers=4
```